# convert yuv to avi using gstreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, avi, yuv

I want to convert an avi file to an yuv file. I tried using

```
ffmpeg -i <input.avi> <output.yuv>
```

but not getting converted. can anybody suggest me conversion using gstreamer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you solve it using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -o out.yuv
```

Converts any input to 420 planar yuv.